# Arithmetic Fuchsian groups -- equivalent definitions?

Tags: reference-request, geometric-group-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I am trying to learn about arithmetic Fuchsian groups from Svetlana Katok's book *Fuchsian groups*.

At the beginning of Chapter 5, it says that the Fuchsian group is ***arithmetic*** if it has integer coefficients. Also when I search, a more precise definition is as the following ([https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~alessandrini/Arith_Reports/6-Arithmetic%20Groups%20from%20Quaternions.pdf](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Ealessandrini/Arith_Reports/6-Arithmetic%20Groups%20from%20Quaternions.pdf)):

> Let $T:PSL(2,\mathbb{R})\to GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ be a finite dimensional linear representation. Then the subgroup $T(PSL(2,\mathbb{R}))\cap GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ lifts to a discrete subgroup $\Gamma:= T^{-1}(T(PSL(2,\mathbb{R}))\cap GL(n,\mathbb{Z}))$ of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$. All subgroups of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ obtained in this manner and all their subgroups of finite index are called ***arithmetic Fuchsian groups***.

Another definition arising from a quaternion algebra is kind of long and I will omit here, but it is in the above book and the note that I mentioned.

It is not at all clear for me whether the two definitions are equivalent. Along reading, I guess I could make the group of unit quaternions act on the quaternion algebra by left multiplications, which might give a matrix of $GL(4,\mathbb{Z})$.

So my question is, are the two definitions equivalent? If so, how can I see it? Or could you point me to a reference?

Thanks!

Comment: My impression is that proving this equivalence is hard work: the "integer coefficients" version is good theoretically; the "quaternion algebra" version is good constructively; and a lot of work is needed to connect them. For another point of view on low dimensional arithmetic groups see Alan Reid's work.

Comment: For a more general reference on arithmetic groups, which contains the proof of equivalence you are asking about in its full generality, see [the fantastic book by Dave Witte Morris](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0106063.pdf).

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks!! That helps!

Comment: @LeeMosher It is quite clear now for me how to obtain a representation from the lattice generated by quaternions over $\mathbb{Q}$ in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ to $GL(4,\mathbb{Z})$ (by left multiplication), but $-I$ is not in the kernel... Is it clear how to get a representation of the Fuchsian group in $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$?